# Will Ubuntu 9.04 install as a dual-boot-with-XP straight from the .iso, or will I need a separate install of GRUB or LiLo?

Tags: ubuntu, boot

The target machine has XP (SP2) installed, and the goal is to install Ubuntu 9.04 as a dual-boot.  Ten years ago, this would require preparing the disk with something like Partition Magic, but I think there has been progress.  Am I likely to need anything besides the Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go get the latest ISO from Ubuntu.com (unless you have a need for more than 4Gb mem, get the 32-bit version), unpack it onto a memory stick then install away (well reboot your PC!) - just make sure there's enough space for your Ubuntu installation.

One of the early parts of the setup process is a "Partition Magic"-dual-boot-builder-on-steroids interface.... Makes a mockery of how we used to do this in the 'old days'!!

Good luck.

Mike

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop CD is enough.

Check **[WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)**

section: **Resizing Partitions Using the Ubuntu Installer**

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the WUBI install as well.  It's a simple way to get Ubuntu on your machine and if you want to uninstall you can do so by simply going into Add/Remove programs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put my two cents in... If you have the ability to use 64-bit version, go ahead and do it.  Not having the added memory will of course not get you all of the extended functionality/performance, but those programs that are made to take advantage of a 64-bit processor will run faster than in a 32-bit OS.